# Moq It.IsSubtype has no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to mock a generic method, which has a constraint of `T : IFoo`

However moq cannot seem to understand the conversion and gives the following error:

> The type 'Moq.It.IsSubtype<SomeNamepace.IFoo>'
> cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
> 'IMyClass.DoSomething(Action)'. There is no implicit reference
> conversion from
> 'Moq.It.IsSubtype<SomeNamepace.IFoo>' to
> 'SomeNamepace.IFoo'.

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
    }

    class Foo : IFoo
    {

    }

    public interface IMyClass
    {
        public IDisposable DoSomething<T>(Action<T> asd) where T : IFoo;
    }

    public class MyTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();

            mock.Setup(e => e.DoSomething(It.IsAny<Action<IFoo>>())).Returns(Mock.Of<IDisposable>());

// What I want but gives compiler error
//             mock.Setup(e => e.DoSomething(It.IsAny<Action<It.IsSubtype<IFoo>>>())).Returns(Mock.Of<IDisposable>());


// Action<IFoo> would work, but in real code its not used like that
            Action<Foo> myAction = (e) => { };
            var result = mock.Object.DoSomething(myAction);

            result.Dispose(); // Null reference exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be valid from their documentation: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#type-matchers-moq-413

Comment: @madreflection Right but in that case, the nested generic type `IsSubtype<T>` isn't going to implement `IFoo`, surely?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? Obviously the generic passed in is going to be a subtype of `IFoo`. It wouldn't compile if it wasn't?

Comment: @canton7: No, you're right, it doesn't. It only implements Moq's own `ITypeMatcher`. I was only pointing out that it's not a syntax errror (at least not in the way you thought). The documentation says that's what you're supposed to do. It may be a limitation of the library when handling constrained generic type parameters.

Comment: @Liam in my real code DoSomething returns an IDisposable, so I want it to return an Mock<IDisposable>, but removed that for the minimum example. Else I get null exceptions

Comment: But if you replace IFoo with IDisposable It's still an invalid test. There's no point testing that the compiler is working correctly?

Comment: I'm not trying to test the compiler, DoSomething returns IDisposable, but accepts type  T : IFoo. I'm trying to mock the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own type matcher which will implement `IFoo` to match the generic constraint:

```
[TypeMatcher]
public class FooTypeMatcher<T> : IFoo, ITypeMatcher
    where T : IFoo
{
    bool ITypeMatcher.Matches(Type typeArgument)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeArgument);
    }
}
```

And setup:

```
mock.Setup(e => e.DoSomething(It.IsAny<Action<FooTypeMatcher<IFoo>>>())) // will match any Action accepting any IFoo implementation
    .Returns(Mock.Of<IDisposable>());
```

Answer (score 6):

Since `It.IsSubtype<IFoo>` doesn't implement `IFoo`, you can't use it like this. due to the type constraint.

However, you can just use `IFoo` on its own, which should account for any value you pass in since they all need to implement `IFoo`. In other words, the heavy lifting of ensuring the type is correct is already done for you by the type constraint. For example, given a set-up like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    string DoSomething<T>() where T : IFoo;
}
```

Your test code would be simply this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
mock.Setup(e => e.DoSomething<IFoo>()).Returns("cheese");

var result = mock.Object.DoSomething<IFoo>();

Assert.Equal("cheese", result); // true
```

#### EDIT:

After the additional clarification to the question, the answer above still stands, and we can do something similar:

```
mock
    .Setup(e => e.DoSomething<Foo>(It.IsAny<Action<Foo>>()))
    .Returns(new MyDisposableObject());
```

Now we are using `Foo` because we know explicitly the type being passed in so we don't need to worry about the interface anymore. In fact, we can even simplify the code since we don't need to be explicit about the generic type any more:

```
mock
    .Setup(e => e.DoSomething(It.IsAny<Action<Foo>>()))
    .Returns(new MyDisposableObject());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't work for my full example. I extended the code in my original post with more context.

Because Action<Foo> does not get setup by Action<IFoo>

Comment: Well if you know you are going to pass in `Action<Foo>` then use `Foo` instead: `mock.Setup(e => e.DoSomething<Foo>(It.IsAny<Action<Foo>>())).Returns(new Foo());`